# Outer right join doesn't work in NHibernate

Tags: mysql, nhibernate, orm, fluent-nhibernate, hql

So I'm having two tables:

Table 1:

```
Item
id : int
title : varchar
comments : varchar
```

Table 2:

```
Rating
id : int
isUpvote : bit
date : datetime
item_id : int
```

One Item can have several ratings. IsUpvote states whether a Rating is a like or dislike.

I'm using NHibernate to ORM to my MySQL-database.

Want I want to make a kind of trending list of items to show which items have had to most likes in the past time (so from dateTime X to now).

The MySQL code looks like this:

```
select p.id, sum(case when r.isUpvote = b'1' then 1 else 0 END) - sum(case when r.isUpvote=b'0' then 1 else 0 END) as score
from rating as r
right join item as p
on p.id = r.item_id
group by p.id
order by score desc
limit 7;
```

This results in:

> Id - Score
>
> 1 - 2
>
> 2 - 1
>
> 3 - 0
>
> 4 - 0
>
> 5 - 0
>
> 6 - 0
>
> 7 - 0

So I want to do this in NHibernate. I tried but HQL and QueryOver but I just can't figure it out. What I tried is:

```
GetTrendingItems(int nrOfTrendingItems, DateTime fromDate) {
var trendingItems = Session
            .CreateQuery(@"select p, sum(case when r.IsUpvote = 1 then 1 else 0 END) - sum(case when r.IsUpvote=0 then 1 else 0 END) as score
                from Item as p, Rating as r
                where p.Id = r.Point.Id
                group by p.Id
                order by sum(case when r.IsUpvote = 1 then 1 else 0 END) - sum(case when r.IsUpvote=0 then 1 else 0 END) desc")
            .SetMaxResults(nrOfClimbers)
            .List();
}
```

and I tried:

```
GetTrendingItems(int nrOfTrendingItems, DateTime fromDate) {
DBRating dbRatingAlias = null;
        var iets = Session.QueryOver<DBRating>(() => dbRatingAlias)
            .Where(r => r.Date > fromDate)
            .OrderBy(Projections.Conditional(
                Restrictions.Where(() => dbRatingAlias.IsUpvote),
                Projections.Constant(1),
                Projections.Constant(-1))).Desc
            .Right.JoinQueryOver<DBPoints>(r => r.Point)
            .Take(nrOfClimbers)
            .List();
}
```

I'm kinda losing hope here. Can someone help me?

---

Update:
The HQL generates this SQL:

```
 select
    dbpoints0_.id as col_0_0_,
    sum(case 
        when dbrating1_.isUpvote=1 then 1 
        else 0 
    end)-sum(case 
        when dbrating1_.isUpvote=0 then 1 
        else 0 
    end) as col_1_0_,
    dbpoints0_.id as id3_,
    dbpoints0_.active as active3_,
    dbpoints0_.title as title3_,
    dbpoints0_.comments as comments3_,
    dbpoints0_.score as score3_ 
from
    points dbpoints0_,
    Rating dbrating1_ 
where
    dbpoints0_.id=dbrating1_.points_id 
group by
    dbpoints0_.id 
order by
    sum(case 
        when dbrating1_.isUpvote=1 then 1 
        else 0 
    end)-sum(case 
        when dbrating1_.isUpvote=0 then 1 
        else 0 
    end) desc limit ?p0;
?p0 = 10 [Type: Int32 (0)]
```

and the Fluent generates this SQL:

```
SELECT
    this_.id as id6_0_,
    this_.owners_id as owners2_6_0_,
    this_.points_id as points3_6_0_,
    this_.isUpvote as isUpvote6_0_,
    this_.date as date6_0_ 
FROM
    Rating this_ 
WHERE
    this_.date > ?p0 
ORDER BY
    (case 
        when this_.isUpvote = ?p1 then ?p2 
        else ?p3 
    end) desc limit ?p4;
?p0 = 25-5-2015 22:39:49 [Type: DateTime (0)],
?p1 = True [Type: Boolean (0)],
?p2 = 1 [Type: Int32 (0)],
?p3 = -1 [Type: Int32 (0)],
?p4 = 10 [Type: Int32 (0)]
```

Comment: Have you looked at the SQL NHibernate is generating? If so, where exactly is it going wrong?

Comment: I edited the most because it was to big of a content to put in a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a stored procedure in de MySQL database

```
DELIMITER //
create procedure getTrending
    (IN $getClimbers bool,
    IN $fromDate DateTime,
    IN $nrOfTrending int)
Begin
    if ($getClimbers) then
        select p.id, p.active, p.title, p.comments, 
        sum(case when r.isUpvote = b'1' and r.date > $fromDate then 1 else 0 END) - sum(case when r.isUpvote=b'0' and r.date > $fromDate  then 1 else 0 END) as score
        from rating as r
        right join points as p
        on p.id = r.points_id
        group by p.id
        order by sum(case when r.isUpvote = b'1' and r.date > $fromDate then 1 else 0 END) - sum(case when r.isUpvote=b'0' and r.date > $fromDate  then 1 else 0 END) desc
        limit $nrOfTrending;
    else
        select p.id, p.active, p.title, p.comments,
        sum(case when r.isUpvote = b'1' and r.date > $fromDate then 1 else 0 END) - sum(case when r.isUpvote=b'0' and r.date > $fromDate  then 1 else 0 END) as score
        from rating as r
        right join points as p
        on p.id = r.points_id
        group by p.id
        order by sum(case when r.isUpvote = b'1' and r.date > $fromDate then 1 else 0 END) - sum(case when r.isUpvote=b'0' and r.date > $fromDate  then 1 else 0 END) asc
        limit $nrOfTrending;
    end if;
end //
DELIMITER ;
```

and then called it from my C#-code with:

```
public virtual List<DBPoints> GetClimbers(int nrOfClimbers, DateTime fromDate)
        {
            OpenSession();
            var query = Session.GetNamedQuery("getTrending");
            query.SetBoolean("getClimbers", true);
            query.SetDateTime("fromDate", fromDate);
            query.SetInt32("nrOfTrending", nrOfClimbers);
            var pointList = query.List<DBPoints>();
            CloseSession();
            return pointList.ToList();
        }
```

For Nhibernate there needs to be made a mapping like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
                   assembly="TechDash.Business"
                   namespace="TechDash.Business.Models.Database">

  <sql-query name="getTrending">
<return class="DBPoints" />
call getTrending(:getClimbers, :fromDate, :nrOfTrending)
```

Since the names of my columns that are returned are the same as those that are returned when I'm retrieving a Points-object, I don't have to make a new C#-object nor the mapping belonging to that C#-object.